# How to set subtilte in NavHostFragment with the Navigation component?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigationview

```
package `my`.app.ui

import `my`.app.R
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class Support : Fragment(R.layout.appui) {
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        activity.apply {
            this?.actionBar?.title = "title"
            this?.actionBar?.subtitle = "subtitle"
        }
    }
}
```

`NavigationUI` is not supporting set title or subtitle ?

And below is the dependency used for project

```
 - implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
 - implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
 - implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
 - implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `OnDestinationChangedListener` to set the title after your setup method:

```
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
        if (destination.id == R.id.nav_xxx){
            supportActionBar?.title = "My Title"
        }
        //.....
    }
```